# C++ Console only show input when asking for it

Tags: c++, console

I have made some simpel application which uses alphabetic keys to navigate (WASD).
The problem is whenever I use alpabhetic keys it gets displayed on the console.
I usually want the input to display only when specifically asking for it via std::cin, but else it disturbs. I could use arrow keys, but it was interesting how to solve it with alphabetic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your operating System. So, I think that you have to use OS functions to set your console's parameters.